# Chronometer is null even though parent class initialised it

Tags: java, android, android-activity, null, oncreate

I got this weird problem and it's bugging me. I don't understand why I get this NullPointerException when I did initialise chronometer in MainActivity. If I initialise chronometer in SecondActivity the program works fine.

Hopefully someone can clear this up...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(android.widget.Chronometer$OnChronometerTickListener)' on a null object reference
```

-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected Chronometer chronometer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //chronometer gets initialised here but it's still null appearantly
        chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);

        //this works
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#cd2626")));
    }
}
```

-

```
public class SecondActivity extends MainActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

         //if chronometer gets initialised again, program does work.
         //chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1)
     }
}
```

Comment: Does `findViewById` by any chance look for something that `setContentView` defined? If so, call `setContentView` *before* calling `super.onCreate`.

Comment: Calling setContentView before super.onCreate crashed the program, probably because MainActivity needs to call super.onCreate before you can call setContentView. I guess I'll just have to call setContentView in main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include setContentView(R.layout.main_layout); in your mainactivity otherwise findviewbyid will not be able to find chronometer and it will always show null exception

Comment: Thanks this fixed it, would you mind explaining why you need the setContentView in main?

Comment: If you will not set the view to the Activity/Fragment, how can the activity/fragment will know that there is a view(Or Chronometer in your case) .

Answer (score 1):

Your chronometer variable is not initialized in MainActivity.onCreate because layout is inflated (setContentView called) only in SecondActivity.onCreate. So findViewById in your MainActivity has no effect.

In general I recommend not to build class hierarchies aroun Activity. Try to use something else, like interfaces to achieve what you need.

Comment: Thanks this fixed my problem, but why does findViewById not work when you don't inflate layout in Main? And how would you go about modifying the MainActivity class with interfaces?